# Unable to update a state variable inside onRegionChange() method of MapView

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm getting `this.setState is not a function` when trying to update `region` parameter inside **onRegionChange()** method of *MapView*.

```
<MapView
  ref = {(ref) => {this.mapRef = ref}}
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
  onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
  region={this.state.region}>
</MapView> 

 onRegionChange(region_) {
  //console.log(region_);
  this.setState({region:region_}); 
}
// Initial region value in *constructor*

constructor(props){
super(props); 
this.state = { 
        region: {
         latitude: 0,
         longitude: 0,
         latitudeDelta: 0,
         longitudeDelta: 0 
      }
    }
}
```

I have also tried updating the variable with.

`this.state.region.setValue(region_);`

Answer (score 0):

In your `constructor` method add:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onRegionChange = this.onRegionChange.bind(this); //add this
}
```

Comment: This removes the error but the Map is now 'jumpy' when scroll. It seems like there is an issue updating the region data. `longitude`, `latitude`, `latitudeDelta`, `longitudeDelta`